# getting error while using nested form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using nested form in rails , parameters are coming in console but not save into the database table

```
error : Unpermitted parameter: shyain_rekis
```

Is there mistake in aru_params ? If there then, what is the mistake?

```
def aru_params
  params.require(:aru).permit(:shyain_rekis_attributes => [:id, :emp_type, :company_leaving_reason, :_destroy])
end
```

view :

```
<%= f.fields_for :shyain_rekis_attributes do |ff| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= ff.select :emp_type,TShyainTouyouJoshinsho::EMP_TYPE,{}, class: 'form-control' , :disabled => @disabled_field %></td>
        <td><%= ff.text_field :company_leaving_reason, class: 'form-control' , :disabled => @disabled_field %></td>
        <td><%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
            <%= link_to '削除' ,'#' , class: " btn btn-xs btn-danger remove_record" %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

```
Parameters: {"shyain_rekis_attributes"=>{"1555403656594"=> {"shyain_rekis"=>{"emp_type"=>"abc",company_leaving_reason"=>""}, "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

I want to resolve error and save data into database table of nested form

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :sheyain_rekis` in your Aru model? Also do you have the `has_many` defined there too?

Comment: https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/nested-forms-from-scratch i am using this site for the reference to create nested form

Comment: yes i define both @Mike heft

Comment: How are you setting up the form, the parameters are not being submitted correctly

Comment: Ya @Iceman asked my next question about your form. Can you edit your question with your form?

Comment: hope your associations are perfect, can you please show your view?

Comment: ya should look something like `<%= form.fields_for :shyain_rekis_attributes do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You may already have done that, but) To achieve what you want, instantiate the variable in the controller like so:

```
def new
  @aru = Aru.new
# other stuff...
def edit
  @aru = Aru.find(params[:id])
```

Then you have to pass an instance to the parent form tag, so if you have a symbol as the parameter switch it to the instance, something like this:

```
<%= form_for @aru do |f| %>
```

For your nested form you don't need to use `_attributes` as the `fields_for` argument

```
<%= f.fields_for :shyain_rekis do |ff| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= ff.select :emp_type,TShyainTouyouJoshinsho::EMP_TYPE,{}, class: 'form-control' , :disabled => @disabled_field %></td>
        <td><%= ff.text_field :company_leaving_reason, class: 'form-control' , :disabled => @disabled_field %></td>
        <td>
            <%= ff.hidden_field :_destroy %>
            <%= link_to '削除' ,'#' , class: " btn btn-xs btn-danger remove_record" %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to scope the `_destroy` hidden field to your nested form, or it will not destroy the related object.